# Chrome Extension to override css

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I want to develop a Chrome Extension so I can override some Css styling on a particular website.

So here are files:

**manifest.json**:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Modify CSS and HTML",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Lateral blog post demo extension",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "css": ["styles.css"],
    "matches": ["http://www.record.pt/*"]
  }]

}
```

**styles.css**:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower');

.thumb-info h3 {
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive !important;
}
```

I can't get the Google fonts to work. It assumes the cursive type, but not the Google Font. Using Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Any ideas why this happens?
Can someone test on their Chrome and give feedback please?

Comment: Remove !important please

Comment: @Risa__B is correct. `!important` literally overrides everything else.

Comment: i don't think that part of the code is the problem. He wants to override everything else. He says that part of the code works he is looking to make the code above work

Comment: The problem here is that google fonts are not working. If I set "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif; or anything else, it works. Google fonts worked in past, but not now.... weird...

Comment: in the past did you use it in the same website?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have tried referencing external files (mostly js) and was never successful. As I recall there was some restriction from chrome for external files. Besides that I have also noticed in the website there were several cross domain access restrictions. I am not sure if this kind of import would be possible. Also notice that the website has a js bug. It may not run certain codes because of that, however I do not think css would be effected because of that.

When I used to have this issue with js files, after trying all sorts of ways to import, I finally just downloaded the js file and referenced it in the manifest. You can try the same. Either save the fonts content into a separate file or inside your styles.css file.